# how to use next available row in a range

Tags: excel, vba, range

can not figure out how to use the next available cell in column N Range ("N4:N29")

```
If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox "DON'T DO THAT"
Else
    LrowCompleted = Sheets("Budget").range("N4").End(xlDown)
    Sheets("Budget").range("N4" & LrowCompleted + 1) = TextBox1.Text
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. The line with `Lrowcompleted` will return a reference to the last used cell in the row. Since you need the row of the last used cell, call the `.Row` property:

`LrowCompleted = Sheets("Budget").range("N4").end(xldown).row`

Comment: @Byron feel free to mark a working/helpful answer as "accepted", by clicking the hollow checkmark next to the up/down voting buttons near the top of this post. That will give you an instant +2, and the answerer gets +15 virtual internet points =)